AWS DocumentDB BulkWrite Duplicate Key E11000
I have an application running multiple threads with each saving data to a AWS DocumentDB using the following function:
@Transactional
public void save(Collection<MyDocument> documents) {
    Map<String, MyDocument> documentById = new HashMap<>();
    documents.forEach(doc -> documentById.put(doc.getId(), doc));
    BulkOperations bulkOperations = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, MyDocumentEntity.class);
    Query idQuery = new Query(new Criteria("_id").in(documentById.keySet()));
    bulkOperations.remove(idQuery);
    List<MyDocumentEntity> documentEntities = documentById.values().stream()
            .map(MyDocumentEntity::from)
            .toList();
    bulkOperations.insert(documentEntities);
    bulkOperations.execute();
}

There can be multiple documents with the same id coming in, so I put them into a map to make them unique by id, as we are only interested in one event.
Afterwards i delete all having the collected id and insert the new ones.
This is faster than updating which is important for us.
Mapping from MyDocument to MyDocumentEntity does not change the id.
As far as i have understood it, the BulkMode.ORDERED should make sure the delete operation is executed before the insert operation and the @Transactional should suffice to prevent threads from disturbing another thread while saving.
However I keep getting the error com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server xxx. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=416, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: myDocumentEntity index: _id_', details={}}].
I don't understand why this happens or how to fix it.
